# Developing in xampp, Windows. Hosting in Linux. Is it possible?

Tags: xampp, web-hosting, codeigniter-3, php-7

I am creating a website using xampp (PHP 7.0.5, MySQL, Codeigniter 3.0.6) in Windows Environment. Can I use Linux Web Hosting to host this website?

I tried to find the answer from the internet as well as stack overflow but could find any article on this.

Please help!!

Comment: Yes probably you should go through Linux server LAMP to know more about .

Comment: @GK27 Sir, do you mean I will have to transfer my site from xampp to lamp before hosting?

Comment: Yep. LAMP is  type of linux server similar to XAMP in windows . you may have to explore about deployment in linux .

Comment: @GK27 Ok. I will do that. Thank you sir. But is there any way to use Linux Hosting without changing to LAMP?

Comment: Yes, you can use relative directory paths as part of an absolute filepath. It does the correct thing. And is still considered an absolute filepath by the O/S so does what you expect. I never change any of my code as regards filepaths. Except for the 'application bootstrap' file. Which I have to check anyway.

Comment: done correctly - you may need to change one line of code in one file. :) It isn't difficult with a little 'discipline'.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent Thank you sir for the detailed reply. But, as I am complete inexperienced in web hosting, I am finding it a little difficult to follow up. It would be great if you please show me with some screen shots. Thanking you once again.

Comment: Created a [demonstration website for Absolute filepaths with relative directories](http://rfv123.orgfree.com/AbsolutePaths/). There is a link on it to download the source for the website. Just unzip so that you have an `AbsolutePaths` directory in the `XAMPP` 'htdocs' directory and it should work. Check the source for how to the same paths on Windows and Linux without changing any filepaths.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent Thank you very much sir. I am trying this right away.

Comment: Did this help? anything you still having issues with?